# Ajax mailer script not working, what to edit?

Tags: php, javascript, email, jquery

I'm not receiving any emails, what could be the problem ?

ui.js

```
sendEmail = function(username, callback) {
  var msg = getMessage(username);
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'ui.php', 
   data: '***What should I type here ?***', 
   success: callback
  });
```

ui.php

```
<?php
$to = "XXXXXX@gmail.com";
$subject = "you got mail";
$message = $_POST['getMessage'];
$send = @mail($to, $subject, $message);
if(!$send){    
    die();  
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you go directly to `ui.php`?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console or in the call to the PHP page?  Do you have a sendmail program installed?  What happens if you take off the error supression (`@`) in front of the `mail()` function?

Comment: Is the server sending any emails? Can you see any communication in port 25 (SMTP)? Did you try to narrow down the cause by hardcoding some values in your server-side code (e.g., try to send a test message to your gmail) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data should be a hash with the data. So in your case:

```
sendEmail = function(username, callback) {
  var msg = getMessage(username);
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'ui.php', 
   data: { getMessage : 'Actual message' }, 
   success: callback
  });
```

Also make sure you're defining the callback function what you're using in success-callack. You can leave that away if you're not interested in response.

Also there's a [shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post ajax request with POST.

Comment: Great ! got that down, now I need to test the php if it works, and how can i get the php to send to my gmail the usernames of my subscribers. Thanks